# Laravel: using throttle in a custom Login controller

Tags: php, laravel, throttling

This is my login controller function

```
   use ThrottlesLogins;
   protected $maxLoginAttempts = 3;
   protected $lockoutTime = 300;

 public function login(Request $request)
    {       

        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request))
        {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all() , ['credential' => 'required|min:2|max:255', 'password' => 'required|string|min:8', ]);
        $cred = $request->credential;
        $pw = $request->password;
        $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;

        if (filter_var($cred, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
          {
          if (Auth::guard('customers')->attempt(['email' => $cred, 'password' => $pw, 'verified' => 1], $remember))
            {
            return redirect()->route('front');
            }
            else
            {
            return redirect()->route('customer-login-page')->with('error', 'Your credentials do not match');
            }
          }
          else
          {
            if (Auth::guard('customers')->attempt(['contact' => $cred, 'password' => $pw], $remember))
             {
              return redirect()->intended(route('front'));
             }
            else
            {
            return redirect()->route('customer-login-page')->with('error', 'Your credentials do not match');
            }
          }

    }



  protected function hasTooManyLoginAttempts(Request $request)
    {
       return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
           $this->throttleKey($request), $this->maxLoginAttempts, $this->lockoutTime
       );
    }
```

It's not working. I've tried failed login attempts more that 3 times and still not getting throttled. AND
Even when I post the correct credentials, the login and redirect works but when I check the request I get a

> 302 FOUND error

in the network tab

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the trait know that you are performing a login attempt by calling `$this->incrementLoginAttempts($request)` ([see code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9b2756810bb38601da98149c77d6e24bee8a2fc5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ThrottlesLogins.php#L33)). You can place this call right after your existing throttle check:

```
if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request))
{
    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}

$this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

// other code
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this. It works.  But  after the attempts I get a blank page not a message

Comment: That's interesting. `sendLockoutResponse($request)` seems to throw a `ValidationException`, which means `return` will do nothing at all. Maybe you try it with a `try { } catch (ValidationException $e) { }` instead? Although that doesn't explain how the original code in the [AuthenticatesUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5d6eb7d17b474cb61ba89542e894336f19b1f944/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php) trait works.

Comment: Ok, after some more thinking through this, it seems that the `ValidationException` is catched by an internal exception handler and transformed into a `Response` accordingly. The `return` in front of the exception seems to be without any effect. So my best guess would be that you have made some changes to your exception handler or something else is broken. Please have a look at your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
```

Instated of

```
use ThrottlesLogins;
```